# Common Lisp; Paradigms of AI Programming examples not working

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I got Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming because I've read tons of good reviews about it, but [every example](http://norvig.com/paip/README.html) have errors, I tried using SBCL and Lispworks on windows 7.

For example, I'm trying to write a scheme interpreter, [this file](http://norvig.com/paip/interp1.lisp) has undefined functions, [this file](http://norvig.com/paip/interp2.lisp) has undefined operators, and [this file](http://norvig.com/paip/interp3.lisp), there's something wrong with REQUIRE.

Google didn't help, it seems that I'm the only guy having these errors. The book is really amazing but I'm dying to see a working code. would you please copy/paste and see if it works for you? Is it only me who has these kind of errors?

Should i try a Clisp or something? Should i contact the author asking him to correct his code? but he is a director at google now, he won't reply to a stupid guy like me, therefore i'm coming here for help, you can't find lisp experts everywhere

Comment: "Google didn't help, it seems that I'm the only guy having these errors" - that should be a clue...

Comment: When i say none of the examples work, i really mean it, try the othello game for example, but i'm trying to follow the scheme example

Comment: @MitchWheat if that's the case, please try to compile the scheme example, if it works fine, i'll delete the question right now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you are treating each file as a stand-alone system. They are not independent, but build on each other.

You need to follow the instructions in the README file you link to instead of loading the individual files.